# Can I use a script on a website to make the iPad open an application?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, titanium, multimedia

I'm currently developing an iOS application that needs do display Rich-Media-PDF's. We do all know that iOS has it's troubles in dealing with Multimedia PDF's especially in the standard preview.

My question is: Can I redirect the „View PDF" button of my App to an external websites that has absolutely no content but a script running in the background making the iPad launch the Acrobat Reader to display the PDF on the iPad, given the Acrobat Reader is installed on the device that opens the script page?

Comment: You mean : your application -> your web site with a hosted PDF -> Acrobat Reader on the iPad if installed?

Comment: Hi ForguesR, of course that would be the absolute perfect flow. But as for know, it would be sufficient if the flow would be:

My application ---> Linking to an external Website with a script ---> Opening the Acrobat Reader on the iPad (if installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes you can. For iOS apps, there are these things called URL schemes. Basically, each app can have a scheme similar to a website (i.e. myapp://do/something).

So the user in your app would click "View PDF", and it would open Safari and redirect to your web page. On this page you can have a script that calls to open the Acrobat Reader app.

The problem is that I'm not sure if Adobe has enabled this app URL in their Acrobat Reader app. I did a quick Google but couldn't find anything, but if they do have one it would be something like (adobeacrobat://). If you can confirm that the Acrobat Reader app does indeed have a url scheme set up, then yes you can definitely do this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I also did a quick google search that ended up in Adobes official forum. It seems that in over 2 years, since one member asked for a URL scheme, Adobe has yet to come up with the embedding of a URL scheme in the Reader application for iOS. 

Looks like I'll have to use a different app that allows editing of interactive PDF's and is also addressable via an URL scheme.